# I have a VAR model, can I use the R-square values to explain how good the model explains the dependent variable and if yes, how will it be done

Tags: time-series, interpretation, r-squared, vector-autoregression, lags

I have a VAR model, can I use the R-square values to explain how good the model explains the dependent variable (explanatory power of the model) and  if yes, how will the values of the R-square be interpreted?

[image]/3ztZ5.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use $R^2$ as a goodness-of-fit measure in a VAR model. There are multiple dependent variables in a VAR model and there is an equation for each one. You can use the $R^2$ for each equation separately. If it is not part of standard output, you can obtain $R^2$ as the square of correlation between the true values and the fitted values. For a concrete dependent variable $Y$, this is $R^2=\text{corr}(Y,\hat Y)^2$.

The interpretation of $R^2$ is the same as in regular regression. It is the proportion of variance in the dependent variable that is explained by the model. It is also the square of the correlation between the true and the fitted values of the dependent variable.

Comment: ok but how do i interpret my result above, since in other regressions it gives you just one figure but here in the VAR model , it gives me 4 different values for each variable. So how do i interpret it from the picture attached.

Comment: @ShelleyShelle, you interpret each equation separately, and then the interpretation is the same as in the regular regression case. E.g. `FDIout` has an $R^2=0.82$ which is quite impressive (the model explains the variance in the variable pretty well), while `FDIinf` has an $R^2=0.45$ which is mediocre (the model leaves more than half of the variance unexplained).

Comment: Okay , well understood now. Thank you

Comment: @ShelleyShelle, you are welcome! If my answer is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).